# Is there a way to adding custom sections consecutively with gcc linker?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, attributes, sections

I'm developing C on windows and build with mingw. I want to define some variables in custom sections. And these sections must be adding consecutively. I created new sections like that,

```
__attribute__ ((section(".section2")))
volatile int var1=1;
__attribute__ ((section(".section2")))
volatile int var2=2;
__attribute__ ((section(".section1")))
volatile int var3=3;
__attribute__ ((section(".section1")))
volatile int var4=4;
__attribute__ ((section(".section1")))
volatile int var5=5;
__attribute__ ((section(".section1")))
volatile long int var6=6;
```

I checked the sections with objdump and result is

```
Contents of section .section2:
 0000 01000000 02000000                    ........
Contents of section .section1:
 0000 03000000 04000000 05000000 06000000  ................
```

As I said, i want to adding these sections consecutively. I printed variables addresses.

```
var1 : 00403000
var2 : 00403004
var3 : 00404000
var4 : 00404004
var5 : 00404008
var6 : 0040400C
```

My problem is section2 is not following section1. Var1's address has to be "00404010" and var2's address has to be "00404014".

So what should i do for that? Does such compile options or linker options exist?

Thanks in advance! and sorry for my sloppy english.

Comment: Should not be `var1` `00404010` and `var2` `00404014` ?

Comment: sorry my mistake. you are right. vay 1 should be 00404010 and var 2 00404014.

Comment: I just changed the order of variable declaration, and it worked (var1 and var2 after the others).

Comment: i tried to as you said. this time var3's address = 00403000 and var1's address = 00404000. So i think, section2 is not following section1 again. I expected, if var3's address is 00403000, var1's address should be 00403014. And also i can define variables in different .c files. so i think need to add some compiler or linker options.